# Noninformative prior for Gaussian precision as the special case of Gamma distribution with both parameters being zero

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution, uninformative-prior, precision

The question is from page 120 of book "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" by Christopher M. Bishop. I excerpt it as follows:

[image]

The definition of gamma distribution $\textrm{Gam}(\lambda|a_0,b_0)$ in Eq (2.146) is as follows:

[image]

As the book says, the noninformative prior for precision $\lambda$ is
$$p(\lambda)\propto1/\lambda.$$

By the book, this prior distribution is a special case of $\textrm{Gam}(\lambda|a_0,b_0)$ when $a_0=b_0=0$. To make the exponential of $\lambda$ equal to -1, I understand that $a$ should be 0 in Eq (2.146). To remove the exponential factor in Eq (2.146), I understand that $b$ should be 0. But how about $\Gamma(a)$ in Eq (2.146)? We know $\Gamma(0)$ is infinity, so when $a_0=b_0=0$, the right side of Eq (2.146) reduces to constant 0, not $1/\lambda$. So, how to understand that noninformative prior $1/\lambda$ is the special case of $\textrm{Gam}(\lambda|a_0,b_0)$ when $a_0=b_0=0$? Thanks.

Comment: $p(\lambda)$ is only proportional to $1/\lambda$, not equal to it. Also, $1/\lambda$ is an improper prior, which does not integrate to one, so that constants like $\Gamma(0)$ do not play their usual role of acting as a normalization constant that ensures integration to 1. It is also rather a limiting case to take both parameters equal to zero, as the gamma distribution has strictly positive parameters.

Comment: There is no Gamma(0,0) distribution so, as @ChristophHanck said, it is to be understood as a limiting case or, in topological terms, a *closure* of the set of priors.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. It took me quite a while to finally understand that. To use a proper density (gamma) to approximate an improper density ($1/\lambda$), the proper one is extended to the extent that is beyond its capacity, so its density value should be infinitely small compared to the improper one. This is reflected in $\frac{1}{\Gamma(a_0)}$ when $a_0\to0$. Another example is noninformative prior for location parameter of a Gaussian distribution obtained by taking $\sigma_0^2\to\infty$ in the conjugate prior. ......

Comment: Small as $\frac{1}{\Gamma(a_0}$ is, it's still nonzero because we are taking limit, so we still have the (approximate) proportional relation $\textrm{Gam}(\lambda|a,b)\dot\propto\frac{1}{\lambda}$ when $a\to0$ and $b\to0$, consistent with the noninformative prior.